# How to fix redirection page after session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a sample website using ASP.NET C# with session timeout when idling, I used JavaScript for my session timeout, my JavaScript code is working I've set the session timeout to 10 seconds for my testing, after 10 seconds it will redirect to Login page and my MasterLayout is not reset, and after 10 seconds again it will show a message again that your session is ended.

I tried to set a session timeout in web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="2"></sessionState>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And authentication:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="1" />
      </authentication>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

After the session has expired, the redirection page is not working.

This is my code in JavaScript:

```
window.setTimeout("endSession();", 10000);
function endSession()
{
    alert("Your session has expired. You will be redirected to the login page.");
    window.location("Login.aspx");
}
```

after 10 seconds it will redirect to login page, but the MasterLayout is not reset and after 10 seconds again it will show message again.

I expect the output after 10 seconds it will redirect to login page, and the masterlayout is like fresh from the start, like the first run of website and after 10 seconds no more message will pop out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `window.location.replace("Login.aspx");` or `window.location.href = 'Login.aspx';`
Both will redirect you the login page. But:

`location.replace` = will not add the current page to the history. Thus will not be able to go back when navigating back button.

`location.href` = this will add the current page to history. User can then go back to it when clicking back button.

I guess it is more resonable to use `location.replace` in your case.